# jasperreports. iReport. форматирование по значению элемента textfield

Tags: jasperreports

В секции `Detail` находится один элемент `textfield`, завязанный на JavaBean `datasource`, таким образом отчет вывод просто список. Возможно ли в зависимости от определенного значения `textfield`, придать ему полужирное начертание?